# Android JSON Live updates

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, live-update

I can't figure out how to get live updates in android from a json api that updates every 2-3 seconds. I've managed to download the JSON code and then create some arrays and log them, but I the values from the json api change every 2-3 seconds and I have no idea how to redownload the JSON. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();

    String result = null;
    try{
        result = task.execute("thelinkIuse").get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;


        while (true) {
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        try {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                symbols.add(jsonPart.getString("symbol"));
                bids.add(jsonPart.getString("bid"));
                asks.add(jsonPart.getString("ask"));


            }

            Log.i("Symbols", String.valueOf(symbols));
            Log.i("Bids", String.valueOf(bids));
            Log.i("Asks", String.valueOf(asks));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("failed", "failed");
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    result =new DownloadTask().execute("thelinkIuse").get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },0,5000);
```

This will call the asynctask every 5 seconds, thus fetching the updated JSON string

Comment: hi @user3450385    "it logs failed every 5 seconds" – user3450385 1 hour ago. An asyncTask can only be executed once you should consider using a factory to get a new instance. Also can you explain the failures happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Im thinking you need some kind of polling mechanism. Look at Firebase Notifications because what you could do is have your server side code post an http request to the firebase server and that will trigger a server side push notification to your app in which you will have a receiver which will trigger the retrieval process

Comment: I started using firebase. I was thinking of storying that JSON from mylink on the firebase server. Do you have any idea on how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely sure about the updates occur every 2-3 seconds then you can periodically call the AsyncTask execute method. This is not considered a very good practice but can get your work done. Something on these lines:

```
private Timer autoRefresh;

autoRefresh=new Timer();
    autoRefresh.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   String result = null;
                  try{
                  result = task.execute("thelinkIuse").get();
                  } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
}

                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, your_time_in_miliseconds);
```